# nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I've got a spring web app where I need to run a json service.

Below is the dispatcher-servlet of my program.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!--  SPECIFIC CONFIGURATIONS -->
    <import resource="springConfigurations/common-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="springConfigurations/mvc-config.xml"/>

    <!--  COMMON CONFIGURATIONS -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And this is the views.xml code.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView"/>

</beans>
```

I get the following error in the console which I stated in the question header.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView] for bean with name 'jsonView' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at com.jkcs.touchpos.server.jetty.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:19)
    at com.jkcs.touchpos.server.jetty.ServerRunner.<init>(ServerRunner.java:12)
    at com.jkcs.touchpos.server.jetty.JettyStart.startServer(JettyStart.java:22)
    at com.jkcs.touchpos.application.start.TouchPosApplication.main(TouchPosApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView] for bean with name 'jsonView' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver.initFactory(XmlViewResolver.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver.afterPropertiesSet(XmlViewResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1258)
    ... 45 more
2013-04-22 09:44:09.028:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9157
```

I added all the necessary JAR files but still the error appears. Please help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have all the necessary jars. Go to [this maven page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.spring-json/spring-json/1.3.1), download the JAR or use the `pom` dependency. Add the jar to your classpath when you compile and run your application

Comment: Added them where and how? They are definitely not found by the application launcher if you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`.